# How to search a SpannableString without knowing the exact substring

Tags: java, android, spannablestring

I want to search a spannable string to find the index of a certain substring which I don't know the length or exact characters of eg `[size=??]` where the question marks could be any characters or substring of any length. If possible I'd also like to know the length of such a string found.

(edit) Example:
If a string such as `"string [size=212] more string"` was given I want it to return the index, so in this case `7` and the length of `[size=212]`, in this case `10`

Comment: You can use a regex and a matcher and then get the substring and thus the length

Comment: Please include a minimal input and expected output in your question.

Comment: @Darkman I've edited it to include an example

Comment: @Darkman the index is from `[`, my mistake for forgetting to count from 0, and the 10 is the length of everything inside the square brackets including the square brackets itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this job by using **Pattern** and **Matcher**.

```java
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String str = "string [size=212] more string [size=212] more string here";
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\[size=[0-9]+\\]");
        Matcher mat = pat.matcher(str);

        int index, lastIndex = 0, length, value;

        while(mat.find()) {
            final String found = mat.group(0);
            value = Integer.parseInt(found.replaceAll("^\\[size=|\\]$", ""));
            length = found.length();
            index = str.indexOf(found, lastIndex);
            lastIndex += length;

            System.out.printf("index: %d, length: %d, string: %s, value: %d%n", index, length, found, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```java
index: 7, length: 10, string: [size=212], value: 212
index: 30, length: 10, string: [size=212], value: 212
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this out and accept your answer after it works, I know it might be a bit late to ask but any way to get the value after the = sign too? so 212

Comment: @Tamzid See my edited.

Comment: There is a typo there. Change this `lastIndex += length;` to this `lastIndex = index + length;`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use regular expressions to extract the substring.
Once you get it, Search match using a function indexOf , that will give you the first index of occurence of your substring.

Note:please give more details to your question

Comment: I've edited it to give an example, how exactly would you use regex to extract the substring?